# How to remove via Regex text around

Tags: regex, notepad++

How we can remove in Notepad++ with regular expressions the not needed text around a specific string? The string with numbers don't has to be removed. The numbers (string) we need is surrounded always by "onRemoveVariable([0-9]*)".

Source:

```
<table>
<tr><td style="css">
<a href="#" onclick="onRemoveVariable(12354);">del</a>
<a href="#" onclick="onEditVariable(1235446);">edit</a>
</td></tr>
<tr><td style="css">
<a href="#" onclick="onRemoveVariable(1231584);">del</a>
<a href="#" onclick="onEditVariable(12354631);">edit</a>
</td></tr>
```

Result:

```
12354
1231584
```

Does anybody has an idea?

Beste regards
Mario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this regex to delete everything except the numbers between the `onRemoveVariable` parts:

```
^.*?onRemoveVariable\((\d+)\).*$|.*
```

This will attempt to get the numbers first, and if not found, match the whole line.

Replacement string:

```
$1
```

If the number was matched, the replacement string will thus put only the number back. If not, then `$1` will be null and the result will be an empty line.

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/zS2oC0/1)

If you now want to remove the multiple blank lines, you can use something like:

```
\R+
```

And replace with:

```
\r\n
```

Then remove manually any remaining empty lines (there can be at most 2 with this replace, one at the beginning and one at the end). `\R` matches any line break and `\R+` thus matches multiple line breaks. The above thus replaces multiple line breaks with single line breaks.

---

```
^                      # Beginning of line
  .*?                  # Match everything until...
  onRemoveVariable\(   # Literal string oneRemoveVariable( is matched
  (\d+)                # Store the digits
  \)                   # Match literal )
  .*                   # Match any remaining characters
$                      # End of line
|                      # OR if no 'onRemoveVariable(` is found with digits and )...
  .*                   # Match the whole line
```

Answer (score 1):

You need find all digits `\d+` with `onRemoveVariable(` before it and `)` after it.
Use lookahead and lookbehind assertions.

```
(?<=onRemoveVariable\()(\d+)(?=\))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex to match just numbers you want :

```
/onRemoveVariable\((\d+)\)/g
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/jA4rG5/1) (Look at the match information on the right panel)

Hope it helps.